# jQuery mobile show loader for custom loading process?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, setinterval, jquery-mobile-loader

I'm building a web application that is rich in images and interactive elements. For these reasons I only want to display the page once all images are loaded:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    $('.ui-content').hide();
    var imgs = $(".ui-content img").not(function() { return this.complete; });
    var count = imgs.length;
    if (count) {
        imgs.load(function() {
            count--;
            if (!count) {
                $(".ui-content").show()
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".ui-content").show();
    }
});
```

I need to either a) remove the loader completely and replace it with my own, or b) have the  loader stay up until the above function finishes.

How do I either remove the loader or keep it up until not needed?

Comment: Usually you can just call `$.mobile.loading('hide');` and `$.mobile.loading('show');`

Comment: Have you tried    $.mobile.loading('hide'); ?

Comment: @m90 Tried that, doesn't work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery Mobile custom loader

**Solution**:

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vdgB5/

`Mobileinit` event must be initialized before jQuery Mobile is initialized and after jQuery. Also some additional changes to css must be done for this to work.

First of all, we need to override default `ui-loader-default` class because its opacity is to low and final spinner is hard to see. Change opacity value how ever you want.

```
.ui-loader-default {
    opacity: 1 !important;      
}
```

And this is our spinner.

```
.custom-spinner {
    width: 37px !important;
    height: 37px !important;
    background-image:url('http://pictures.reuters.com/ClientFiles/RTR/Images/ajax-loader.gif');
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a working example:

Code example

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <style>

            .ui-loader-default {
                opacity: 1 !important;      
            }

            .custom-spinner {
                width: 37px !important;
                height: 37px !important;
                background-image:url('http://pictures.reuters.com/ClientFiles/RTR/Images/ajax-loader.gif');
                opacity: 1 !important;
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
                $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
                $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
                $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
                $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "<i class='custom-spinner'></i>";
            }); 
        </script>       
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
            $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){        
                $.mobile.loading( 'show');          
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
                <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            </div>

            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

## Programmatic execution of jQuery mobile ajax loader

Some browsers, including webkit browser like Chrome have a programmatic execution of jQuery mobile ajax loader. They can be executed manually with serinterval, like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#index', function(){     
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);    
});

$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){  
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);      
});
```

Comment: using this code i am able to click on back page, is there any option which doesn't allow click on page while loading.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do. In the documentation there's a few things you can do with the loader:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/page-loading

As some other people have said, you can make the loader appear/disappear by calling it manually.

```
$.mobile.loading("show");

$.mobile.loading("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

A technique that I have used when bootstrapping is to have the first data-role="page" div as a loading screen.  After bootstrapping I programmatically transition to the home page using changePage:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#home" , { reverse: false, changeHash: false } );
```

Here is a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/Esf7H/